# (Conceptual) Which technique/pattern to use when a thread changes program parameters during execution? (multithreading)

Tags: multithreading, mutex, condition-variable, conceptual

I need to change a program with:

- i/o thread A, that receives data from a stream, and
- worker threads X, Y and Z, that do batch processing depending on global parameters acquired and set by A.

However, A cannot change these parameters while X, Y and Z are processing data, or the data would be corrupted. The changes should only be valid for the next batches.

**A number of ideas has passed through my mind:**

-1. When A receives changes, it has XYZ stop when they are done with latest batches. It then changes the global parameters and allows XYZ to resume.

-2. XYZ keep a local copy of the global parameters and update it every time they are done with a batch, thus taking in any changes. While A is changing the parameters, XYZ have to wait to access them. (I believe this technique is called mutex).

While thinking about it, it occurred to me that this must be a fairly common situation and that solutions for this must already exist. Is there a pattern that solves this (maybe 1 or 2 with an established name)? If not, what do you think of proposals 1 and 2? A mutex looks sufficient for 2, but how could 1 be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Thread A maintains a volatile/atomic pointer to an immutable parameter object.

X/Y/Z grab their own copy of this pointer just before processing a batch, and use the parameter object.

When A gets a parameter change, it creates an entirely new parameter object and updates the pointer to it.

If you're using a language with garbage collection, then that's all you have to worry about.  If you're using C++, then you can use `std::shared_ptr` to manage the lifetime of the parameter objects.